# jqGrid set the attribute of inline edit input box

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

We are using jqGrid free version 4.13.5, the inline edit is enabled.

I want to set the input attribute `dir` to `auto` and also set a class for the input.

According to http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules I find that the grid has `edittype:'custom'` that `custom_element` and `custom_value`functions should be implemented,

I wonder if new version of `jqGrid` has a better way ( without the need of a `custom` edit type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question then you need just use `editoptions` with attributes, which you need to set on the `<input>` of inline editing:

```
editoptions: { dir: "auto", "class": "someClassName" }
```